# Генерация последовательности битов

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Вот у меня есть массив массивов битов. Мне надо в первый массив сгенерировать не повторяющиеся массивы битов. Битов в массиве может быть любое заданное кол-во (например, задали 10 и будут генерироваться массивы с 10 битами). Биты могут повторятся, а сами массивы битов нет. Как это реализовать?

Comment: какова максимальная длина массива бит? Сколько таких массивов надо сгенерировать, 1,2, 5 или все возможные? Если все возможные то перед вами классическая комбинаторная задача генерации перестановок заданной длины с повторами.
Если максимальная длина массива бит ограничена 64 штуками, то вполне можете использовать тип uint64 и раскладывать числа в двоичную систему.

Comment: @teran Я же написал, что длину задаёт переменная, т.е. она может быть различная. Мне надо сгенерировать все возможное, а потом некоторые отсеить по моему алгоритму

Comment: а я и не спрашивал, какая именно должна быть длина. я спросил каково **максимальное значение** длины.

Comment: @teran А, 32 скорее всего

Comment: разложив все числа от `0` до `2^N` (где `N`-длина массива) в двоичный вид вы получите полный набор всех возможных вариантов интересующих вас массивов. Более того, возможно с помощью битовых операций, вы сможете отсеять нужные числа по вашему алгоритму. Например, выкинуть массивы, где скажем третий бит нулевой.

Comment: в общем, дополните лучше свой вопрос конкретным примером что дано, и что надо получить.

Comment: @teran Ну, пример из задачи, из за числа которых я решил сделать эту программу. Есть кодировка, которая кодирует слова буквами A (это 0) и B (это 1). Все слова длинной 9 символов. Надо вывести все слова, исключая те, где символ B стоит рядом с другим символом B

Comment: Ну, а как вам поможет генерация последовательностей битов для этой задачи?